# CSS Animation Inline Style Disappears in Dev Tool When Animation Ends - How to capture them?

Tags: css, css-animations

Some elements on a web page are configured with animation when the page loads. Animation properties such as animation duration, delay, etc are visible in the Chrome dev tool (element tab) as inline style when the animation is running, but they disappear as soon as the animation ends. The animation values under the Computed tab also disappear when the animation ends.

How can I find out the onload animation properties? E.g. Is there a way to capture the animation properties before they disappear? Or are they available elsewhere in the dev tools?

Appreciate any advice on this.

Thank you.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible code

Answer (score 0):

You could try `window.getComputedStyle` of the element, and in that object you will find the css defined properties, including the animation definitions

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle

Comment: The results I get from getComputedStyle are what I see under the Computed tab in the dev tools. However, they do not contain the animation properties, which were in the inline style of the element when the animation starts and removed when the animation ends

Comment: You cannot get previous properties from the time that javascript is execute, maybe you should try a different approach ?

Comment: Thank you. Any suggestions on a different approach?